# MySQL join question

Tags: mysql, self-join

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to combine the following two queries into one using a self-join and, if so, how to do it?

Query 1:

```
   SELECT pm.username AS user,
          uc.content_id AS id,
          value AS filename,
          name,
          moderation_status AS status,
          uc.parent_content_id
     FROM myweb.ugc_meta um
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_content uc ON uc.content_id = um.item_id
LEFT JOIN myweb.userbase_member pm ON uc.user_id = pm.id
    WHERE uc.content_type ='my.photo'
      AND uc.promoted = '1'
      AND moderation_status='passed'
    LIMIT 10
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT value
  FROM myweb.ugc_meta um
 WHERE um.item_id = '4780c650137a3409901286'
-- (item_id is the content_parent_id from query 1)
```

`ugc_meta` contains the album name for photos in `ugc_content`. `ugc_content` contains rows for albums AND photos. `rows` representing photos have a `parent_content_id` which is the `content_id` for the parent row. I don't have the option of changing the table or DB structure.

At the moment I am running a new query (query2) for every result row from query 1 which is sub optimal ;-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply use a LEFT JOIN to the ugc_meta table using a different alias in order to achieve your parent table join like so:

```
SELECT pm.username AS user,
          uc.content_id AS id,
          value AS filename,
          name,
          moderation_status AS status,
          uc.parent_content_id,
          parent.`value`
     FROM myweb.ugc_meta um
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_content uc ON uc.content_id = um.item_id
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_meta parent ON uc.parent_content_id = parent.item_id
LEFT JOIN myweb.userbase_member pm ON uc.user_id = pm.id
    WHERE uc.content_type ='my.photo'
      AND uc.promoted = '1'
      AND moderation_status='passed'
    LIMIT 10
```

I used a LEFT JOIN because presumably there may not always be a parent_content_id in the child table, if there is always a parent in this case then you could use an INNER JOIN which would increase your performance gains more.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to self-join a table you have to assign a different aliase for each, then it should work without problems

```
   SELECT pm.username AS user,
          uc.content_id AS id,
          um.value AS filename, um2.value AS filename2
          um.name, um2.name AS name2
          moderation_status AS status,
          uc.parent_content_id
     FROM myweb.ugc_meta um
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_content uc
       ON uc.content_id = um.item_id
LEFT JOIN myweb.userbase_member pm
       ON uc.user_id = pm.id
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_meta um2
       ON id = um2.item_id
    WHERE uc.content_type ='my.photo'
      AND uc.promoted = '1'
      AND moderation_status='passed'
    LIMIT 10
```

hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT pm.username AS user,
      uc.content_id AS id,
      value AS filename, 
      name,
      moderation_status AS status,
      um2.value AS 
FROM myweb.ugc_meta um
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_content uc ON uc.content_id = um.item_id
LEFT JOIN myweb.userbase_member pm ON uc.user_id = pm.id
LEFT JOIN myweb.ugc_meta om2 ON um2.item_id = uc.parent_content_id
WHERE uc.content_type ='my.photo'
  AND uc.promoted = '1'
  AND moderation_status='passed'
LIMIT 10
```

You might have to put "um." in front of `value`, `name` and `moderation_status` if they're from ugc_meta as it will otherwise be ambiguous whether the value is to be taken from `um` og `um2`.